# Tips or steps on how to visualise a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

**Question**. My doubt is about what steps do you take when given a multivariable function like $z^2 = x^2 - y^2$, to know how it looks like in general. For example if it looks like a bunch of waves, or a mountain, or a ellipsoid, or an sphere, etc. I want to improve in being able to visualize most functions, of course not knowing exactly how they are but a general shape or knowledge about it. I know it's needed a lot of practice but I'm asking for tips/steps not another thing.

Comment: This really depends on the scope of functions you care about. Like, if you just care about sums and differences of squares with a single variable each, it might be worth memorizing how they work. But if you are dealing with very general functions, throwing some calculus at it may or may not help, etc.

Comment: that "calculus" is precisely what I'd love to know, if you are able to explain further in a post I'd appreciate it

Comment: The identity $z^2=x^2-y^2$ is an *equation* (with variables $x,y,z$), *not* a *function*. What kind of visualization are you looking for? By hand? Or some online software?

Comment: You can look my conversation with @Nuke_Gunray but essentially only $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R²}$ functions, like $f(x,y)=x²y$ or $f(x,y)=x²-y²$. And yes only by hand, of course I could use WolframAlpha or Desmos or whatever app to plot it but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Reminder that my objective is to find a VERY general idea of what the function looks like (e.g a mountain, a couple of waves with a hole, etc.) by general tips/guide/steps of whatever kind. (your above comment said to use some "calculus" but he didn't told me what calculus, so there must be a way)

Comment: @Acedium20: No, $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ denotes a function, but $z^2=x^2-y^2$ is not. They are fundamentally different.// (Btw, I would not be notified if you don't write at the beginning of the comment `@user...`.)

Comment: There is no general recipe for multivariable functions because of the complexity. What one usually does is analyze a function case by case. In the case of a function with two variables $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, one may consider its cross-sections where one fixes one variable, or the contour diagrams.

Comment: @user1046533 not even a few tips for so? I refuse to believe it

Comment: @Acedium20: "... one may consider its cross-sections where one fixes one variable or the contour diagrams." This is what you may consider as "tips". Are you familiar with those?

Comment: What recipe do you know for the simpler case of *differentiable* functions with only one variable?

Comment: @user1046533 Recipes I know for $f(x)=x²$ for example? Find the y and x intercepts, I know it looks like a mountain upside up or I know the vertex. And no I don't know what you mean by cross-sections to be fair.

Comment: @Acedium20: You are talking about a *specific* function, which I would not call a "recipe". You are phrasing your question in the post looking for a "general" one.

Comment: @user1046533 the thing is that if I was given a random function in one dimention like $f(x)=\cos²(x)\sin(x)-2$ that isn't as known as the one I posted, I would have the tools (if you don't want to call it recipe) to know generally how it looks, ie find it's derivative to find it's maxima or minima, critical values, increasing and decreasing, etc. But in the $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R²}$ functions I have a total of 0 tools, and I'm just asking for some, I refuse to believe there is just none or just one. Also waiting as well on what's "cross-section" tool you said.

Answer (score 2):

Functions $w = f(x,y,z)$ that depend on all three variables in a non-trivial way are hard to visualize, since they form a $3$-dimensional$^*$ hypersurface
$$\{(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb{R}^4 : w = f(x,y,z)\}\subset\mathbb{R}^4.$$

One way to study this graph is by analyzing its level sets, i.e. by fixing $w_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and looking at the (usually implicitly given) set $$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R} : w_0 = f(x,y,z)\},$$ which can be seen as a $2$-dimensional$^*$ cross section of said $3$-dimensional hypersurface.

which varies when $w\in\mathbb{R}$ is allowed to move. For example, $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$, when seen as $w_0 = x^2+y^2+z^2$, describes a sphere of radius $\sqrt{w_0}$ for $w_0\geq 0$, and is empty for $w_0<0$.

Functions like $w_0 = x^2-y^2-z^2$ are a bit harder to analyze, so it is often wise to use plotting programs to get an implicit plot. Or, using above method again, one can analyze the level sets of this function by fixing one variable. For example, fixing $x = x_0$, one gets $y^2+z^2 = x_0^2-w_0$, so varying $x$ yields circles of varying radius. Solving for $y = y_0$ yields $x^2-z^2 = w_0+y^2$, which yields hyperbolas. But of course, these are $1$-dimensional$^*$ cross sections of a fixed $2$-dimensional$^*$ cross section of a $3$-dimensional$^*$ hypersurface, so one has to do quite some mental gymnastics to get a picture of the whole thing.

So, my tip would be for you to try sketching some of these cross sections, and then have a look at a $3$d-plot of it with Maple or Wolfram Alpha, to see how these sections connect.

$^*$ The dimensions can of course vary from point to point, as long as the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) does not hold.

Comment: This is a thorough general approach. In the example given by Acedium 20, it is simpler to say plainly that the surface is the union of two surfaces with resp. equations :  $z=+\sqrt{x^2-y^2}$ restricted to the domain $\{(x,y)|x \ge y\}$ and $z=-\sqrt{y^2-x^2}$ with domain $\{(x,y)|x \le y\}$.

Comment: I really apreciate your post but I was talking about 3 dimensions functions like the one I posted, if you could redo it with 3 dimensions, and to be clearer, $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R³}$ functions, it would be perfect

Comment: not sure why it doesn't let me edit, i meant $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R²}$ functions

Comment: @Acedium20 To be exact, what you have there is no function in the usual sense. Rather, $z^2 = x^2-y^2$ is an equation. Thus, it does not have a graph, but describes the set $$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : z^2 = x^2-y^2\}.$$
To see it as a function, we first have to bring all variables on one side, which yields $0 = x^2-y^2-z^2 =: f(x,y,z)$. Thus, what we are looking at is the zero-set of $w = f(x,y,z)$. This makes it into a function $f : \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Regarding your comment: A function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$ would just be a curve in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: He means the $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ type of functions

Comment: yeah sorry I couldn't edit, I meant the $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R²}$ type of functions, I'd love to see a general guide on how to visualise a function like Xetrez just showed in general

Comment: rereading your last comment, yeah I know that it is a curve but I want to know it's general looking without details if that's possible and it's guide/tips/steps

Comment: @Acedium20 Well, curves $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ can be come quite complicated, so it's best to analyze it's component seperatly. For example, $$\gamma(t) =\left( \begin{matrix} \cos t \\ \sin t \\ t\end{matrix}\right)$$ is in its first two components just a parametrized circle with radius $1$, while the $z$-component is increasing with $t$, so it yields a spiral.

Comment: But that is a parametric function that is $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{V³}$, isn't it? Am really only interested in $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R²}$, if you can't make a general guide/tips it's okay, I'll try if I can re-edit this so it gets more attention later

Comment: @Acedium20 If you are really only interested in that case, you should check out http://xahlee.info/SpecialPlaneCurves_dir/specialPlaneCurves.html

Comment: thank you, that's a good page but still doesn't show any tip/guide/steps to visualise a function given of R to R².